# Compare a String reconstructed from a byte array with another String

Tags: java, string, arrays

Can somebody please point me to the right direction?

I am receiving a datagram packet, which I store to a string.
When I compare that string, to another one, it will result in false.

Here is the code:

```
private static String KEY = "Iamastring";

    String sentence = new String( receivePacket.getData(), "UTF-8"); //Reconstruct the string
    sentence.trim();
    System.out.println("RECEIVED: " + sentence + " test " + KEY + " test ");
    System.out.println("Length: " + sentence.length() + " " + KEY.equals(sentence));
```

And this is my output:

```
RECEIVED: Iamastring
Length: 1024 false
```

The expected comparison of KEY.equals(sentence) is true.

Comment: That can't be your output. Where are the `test`?

Comment: Strings are immutable so `sentence.trim();` can't affect original string stored in `sentence` reference, but will create and return new trimmed string which you need to store somewhere (you can store it again in `sentence` reference).

Comment: Show us the raw bytes you get from receivePacket.getData() using java.util.Arrays.toString(byte[]).  Perhaps they are not encoded in UTF-8.

Comment: After doing sentence=sentence.trim(); the right output is shown. I believe the output was somehow truncated, and that's why it didnt show RECEIVED: I4mp4ssw0rd test I4mp4ssw0rd test. I added those for the exact reason, to check why nothing shows up when I dud just + KEY (without the test)

Comment: I am getting the expected value now, using what JClassic suggested, thanks all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings aren't mutable :p

Therefore you must assign `sentence.trim()` to a variable, then use that variable for the comparison and the sysouts

```
sentence=sentence.trim();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you expect trim() to help you, you must do

sentence = sentence.trim();

because trim() itself does not modify original string.